Choosing branch of complex valued function
For a problem in an assignment, I have to work with a function that is defined as $$\log\left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right).$$ My question is whether this function is already holomorphic and well-defined (so not multivalued) with the branch cut $\mathbb{C}\backslash ((-\infty,a)\cup \{b\})$ or does it need an additional cut to be well-defined?

It really depends on what values ${z -a \over z-b}$ takes.

Maybe try the branch cut $[a,b]$.

I voted to re-open because this question addresses a common confusion about "branch cuts"...

Your function is holomorphic because it is composed of finitely many holomorphic functions.
To make your function single-valued, you need another cut leading from $b$. Just excluding the point $b$ is not sufficient. The function $f(z)=\frac{z-a}{z-b}$ has a pole in $b$. So if $z$ moves in a trajectory around the pole, then the value $f(z)$ travels somehow around zero also. If $\arg(f(z))$ starts at zero, it goes procedurally to $2\pi$ after one loop. So you have to cut the function there somehow.
You can also rewrite your function as $\log(z-a)-\log(z-b)$. From this, it is now obvious that you need a cut passing through point $b$ the same way as you needed it for the point $a$.

Ah yes, reading your answer I realize it is quite obvious that you have to take another cut, thanks. I am wondering however if instead of taking the cut $(-\infty,a]$ for $\log(z-a)$ and $(-\infty,b]$ for $\log(z-b)$ (so essentially $[a,b]$ for $\log((z-a)/(z-b)$) you could also take the cuts $(-\infty,a]$ for $\log(z-a)$ and $[b,+\infty)$ for $\log(z-b)$? The reason I ask is because for the assignment it would be a problem to work with the first branch (I think).

The cuts must connect the points $a$, $b$ and $\infty$, no matter how. So doing one cut $(-\infty, a]$ and the other cut $[b, \infty)$ is OK.

By $$\frac{1}{\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\log \left(\frac{z-a}{z-b}\right)}=\frac{(a-z) (b-z)}{a-b}$$ its clear, the the defining square polynomial has two simple poles.
The definition of the integral $\int\frac{a-b}{(a-z) (b-z)}\ dz $ on the contour and yields different standard functions as $\log \frac{a-z}{ b-z)}$ or $\tanh^{-1}$.
The branch cut for real $a,b$  can be set on $(-\infty < z <a) \vee (b<z<\infty)$ yielding inverse tangents, smooth over $(a<z<b)$, or along $ (a< z < b)$, yielding the $\log$ above, that outside a circle $|z|> \max (|a|,|b|)$ has an argument inside a circle of radius less 1 around 1, where the logarithm is single valued.
